# vertical center content

Tags: html, css

i have one div and some text inside it. to make my content horizontally and vertically center i use a css. it works fine in firefox but content not being vertically center when test the following code in IE6.

so please guide me what i need add or change in my css.

my html code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vertical Centering</title>
<style>
.content {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
Hello.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please have look at my css and tell me why it is not working in IE also please rectify my css in such a way as a result it should look same in all the browser.

thanks

Comment: Re-post the HTML please.

Comment: display: table-cell; is not supported below IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your text with a span and then set `position:relative` and `top:45%;`

```
 .content span {
    position:relative;
    top:48%;    
}
```

live example: http://jsbin.com/ovabo4/3

Comment: first of all thank u very much for ur great help. but why u specify top:45% why not any other number. plzz expain.

Comment: because the rest 10% (5% of each top and bottom) is the height of the text.

Comment: would u like to explain 10% or 5% things in detail. because i am weak in CSS. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a great guide: [Vertical centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

A good method is to do this, so it is always exactly in the middle *(only works if you have a fixed height div)*

```
<div class="centered"></div>

html, body{height: 100%;}
.centered{height: 500px; width: 500px; position: relative; top: 50%; margin-top: -250px; /* Just use a negative margin that is half the height of your element */
```