# how centered vertically text in list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul>
    <li style="background-color: red"> <div class="test">111 <br /> 111</div></li>
        <li>222</li>
        <li>333</li>
        <li>444</li>
</ul>

.test {
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

how centered vertically text in this list?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/yhmsj/4/

Comment: Set class="test" to <ul> remove it from div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical center content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376099/vertical-center-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is css

```
 .test {
        text-align: center;   
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding:50px 0;
    }

    ul li {
        min-height: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a line-height for your line.

```
<ul>
    <li style="background-color: red"> <div class="test">111 <br /> 111</div></li>
        <li>222</li>
        <li>333</li>
        <li>444</li>
</ul>

.test {
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li {
  min-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This would be a useful solution **if the contents only consist of one line**. However, this is not the case.